# How to make Tippy.js use existing element

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popper.js, tippyjs

I am writing an app where I use Tippy.js to create popups. My HTML code looks like this:

```html
<popup-target popup-id="1">...</popup-target>
...
<popup-content popup-id="1">
    <!-- This content is live -->
</popup-content>
```

To initialize Tippy.js, I use the following code:

```js
tippy(target, 
{
    content(reference) { return document.querySelector("popup-content[popup-id=\"" + identity + "\"]").innerHTML; },
...
}
```

As you can see, I retrieve the innerHTML of the popup-content element. This means that any updates made to the popup-content element will not affect the popup. I would like to set up Tippy.js so that it positions the `<popup-content ..>` without detaching it from the DOM.

I have tried to return Element (not string), and specify appendTo -> body, but Tippy takes the Element and detaches from the DOM, which is undesired because I can not update the popup while it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you ask correctly, but I'm quite sure an element can only be attached to a single parentElement (and DOM) at any given time.

Would it be possible for you to use something like `document.querySelectorAll('popup-content').forEach(instance => {...})` or `for(const instance of document.querySelectorAll('popup-content')) ...` to update all instances the same way?